# HttpContext.Current not recognized by Visual Studio [ ASP.NET MVC ]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project, exactly on a `void method` in a `Controller`, and I need to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies` but **Visual Studio** recognized `Current` as an error, and not shown ( `Current` ) in the **Intilisense**.

This is my method :

```
public void User_Access_Validation()
{

            var T_8 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["T_8"];
            var T_5 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["T_5"];
            var T_T = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["T_T"];

            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookie

            if (T_8 == null || T_5 == null || T_T == null)
            {
                response.Redirect("/Login");
            }
}
```

So please any help ?

Comment: have you added `using System.Web;` in class?

Comment: Yeah I added it

Comment: The method may be in the controller class, but it is not clear if the method is called from a controller action, where a HttpContext should be present - have you tried setting a breakpoint in the controller action you are accessing, and check if the HttpContext.Current is null there as well?

Comment: have you tried `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core and not .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [vivek nuna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527049/vivek-nuna) Mentioned in his answer, you need to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cookies["xxx"]` when you need to work with `Current` in your case.